A Set $A$ is weird if $\left(\sum_{a \in A}a-|A| \right)\in A$, count how many such weird subsets.
I found this problem from this twitter post, but I can't seem to figure out why the following is true...
First let me state the problem,
We say a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ is weird if $$\left(\sum_{a \in A}a-|A| \right)\in A$$
Find the number of weird subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.
I can't understand why only the sets $\{2,i\}$ and $\{1,2,i\}$ for $1<i\le n$ and $3 \le i \le n$. I know by taking example with $A= \{3,4,5\}$ leads to $12 -3=9 \notin A$ but I can't wrap my head around the proof of it.

Suppose you have $|A|=m$. Then, $\sum_{a\in A}a-m\in A$, and
$$\sum_{a\in A}a \geq \frac{(m-1)m}{2}+\left(\sum_{a\in A}a-m\right)$$
Note that the $\left(\sum_{a\in A}a-m\right)$ term must be there, as it an element of $A$, and the $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}=1+2+\cdots+(m-1)$  term  is the sum of the minimum possible sum of the remaining $(m-1)$ elements. Solving this gives $m\leq 3$, so we know that only $|A|=1, 2, 3$ is possible.
$m=1$ can be ruled out quickly, if $A=\{a\}$, then $(a-1)\notin A$.
If we let $A=\{a, b\}$, $a+b-2\in A$, meaning that one element must be 2, and the other one can be anything, hence leading to $A=\{2, i\}(1\leq i\leq n, i\neq 2)$.
If we let $A=\{a, b, c\}$, this gives $a+b+c-3\in A$, meaning that two of them should sum up to 3, giving $A=\{1, 2, i\}$, where $3\leq i\leq n$.

Took me a while to understand why that inequality is true, I see that the term $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\left(\sum_{a \in A} a-n \right)$ cannot be bigger than $\sum_{a \in A} a$ because those term on the RHS is 'not enough' to surpass the sum LHS.

@JAB I edited the answers as two usages of $n$ was present. The solution is more correct in this way. Have a look please.

Great! Thanks, your answer cleared things up a bit.
